# Is there a way in PHP to do something just after the return statement ..?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.7

I am working on API's and I want to do some task after I have returned the response.

Comment: No, Everything after a [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) statement will not be executed.

Comment: Do you mean `return` or `echo` (your question suggests echoing out sth.) ? In the latter, one can obviously do sth. afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

From php.net

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call.

Maybe change your program logic.